# Change badge number

Tags: flutter, dart, badge

In MainPage, it has 2 bottom navigation bar. One is icon with text, another is icon with text and badge number. When my app is launched, the badge is display 3 in second tab. This works fine.

```
  class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MainPageState();
  }

  method(int num) => _MainPageState().showBadge(num);
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  int count = 0;
  TabController _tabController;
  PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex);

    showBadge(3);
  }

  void showBadge(int number) {
    setState(() {
      count = number;
    });
  }

  void onPageChange(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(index,
        duration: kTabScrollDuration, curve: Curves.ease);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: FixTabBarView(
            pageController: _pageController,
            onPageChange: onPageChange,
            tabController: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              TabA(),
              TabB(),
            ]),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.A), title: Text('TabA')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.B,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 1.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.brightness_1, size: 18, color: Colors.red),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 1.0,
                        right: 4.0,
                        child: new Text(count.toString(),
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
              title: Text('TabB'),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          fixedColor: Colors.blue,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

When tab 2 is clicked, I want the badge change to 1,but it throws error.

```
  class TabB extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TabBState();
}

class _TabBState extends State<TabB> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc.callApi().then((onValue){
      MainPage().method(onValue);    // onValue is the number return from server
  });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Tab 2"),
    ));
  }
}
```

**Error**

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
>   ═══════════════════════════════════ The following assertion was thrown
>   building NotificationListener: setState()
>   called in constructor: _MainPageState#6ed53(lifecycle state: created,
>   no widget, not mounted)
>
> This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget
>   that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not
>   necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is
>   already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to call a function from your parent widget to modify the badge when that child widget is loaded, you should add a listener to your _tabController and change the badge when the tab is selected, like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
  _tabController.addListener((){
    if(_tabController.index == 1){
      setState(() {
        showBadge(1);
      });
    }
  });

  _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex);

  showBadge(3);
}
```

Make sure you adjust the `if` for the tab index you want to match.

---

On your `TabB` you can declare that it accepts a `Function` as part of its constructor and then call that function:

```
class TabB extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function showBadge;

  TabB({this.showBadge});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TabBState();
}

class _TabBState extends State<TabB> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc.callApi().then((onValue){
      widget.showBadge(onValue);    // onValue is the number return from server
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Tab 2"),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

On your Main widget:

```
FixTabBarView(
  pageController: _pageController,
  onPageChange: onPageChange,
  tabController: _tabController,
  children: <Widget>[
    TabA(),
    TabB(showBadge: showBadge,),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Looked like I have  to call Widget build in MainPage from PageB first, before call `setState`

Comment: Please check my changes to the response. You don't need to complicate your code so much. There are simpler ways of listening to the changes on a Tab.

Comment: Hey, I appreciated your answer. But in real case for some reason, I need to call an api in tab 2 `initState`. The number should return from tabB to tabA.

Comment: You don't need to call the whole instance of your parent Widget to call a one of it's methods. You can just pass the method down to the child Widget. I'll add it to the response.

Comment: Please check the extra explanation and code I've added to my response. If it's helped you and fixed your issue. Make sure to mark it as correct.